# Is it possible to recover formatted data without operating system?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery

Both partitions, with the windows and the other one were formatted and merged into one not unpartitioned space. Is there a way to recover the data with some bootable program or should I install the operating system first and then some software for recovering? 
Is installing the OS going to overwrite data?

[SystemRecoveryCD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLgXc.jpg)

How can I access and get those 16.91GB of data?

Comment: Short answer yes, it will overwrite!

Comment: @Jay thanks, I am trying solutions from those 2 answers and I'm gonna inform you about the outcome.

Comment: @niksrb In the traditions of stackexchange, looks like this answer will be closed/locked soon. **I suggest posting it in a better network which supports discussions and off topic questions like reddit** (will have to research where to post).

Answer (score 4):

You should definatey NOT install anything new on the disk as it will overwrite data.   Try getting a [linux usb recovery distro](http://lifehacker.com/5984707/five-best-system-rescue-discs) with Photorec (and another disk drive to write data it can recover too).

Comment: Can you please check the image that I have added in question?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [Hiren’s BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/). They have whole section with Recovery tools. And don't install OS on that drive, don't write anything on disk.